# Servlet doPost throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, nullpointerexception

My doPost method keeps throwing a NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Controller.doPost(Controller.java:76)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Line 76 is calling a query to be run through MySQL

```
results = DAO.runQuery(Query);
```

Query is retrieved from a textarea

```
String Query = request.getParameter("textarea");
```

What I am guessing is happening is that Query isn't getting anything from textarea, and that is why the nullpointerexception is being thrown, but I just can't figure out why it isn't getting the text.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only way that line could throw a NPE is if `DAO` is `null`. So you're either not showing us the right line or you're nothing showing us the right stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAO object is null. Look above line 76 to see where it is (or should have been) created.

Comment: Ok, DAO is declared here, `DAO = new DAO(DBEngine.getConnection());` which is getting the MySQL connectionnn `DBEngine = new Engine("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project4", "root", "");`  So something isn't connection correctly to the database. Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe you. :) NPE happens when you dereference something. The only thing being dereferenced on line 76 is the DAO. Any other dereferencing happens on a different line and would report a different error. I am confident that DAO is null because of this. I suggest you look between the DAO instantiation and its use on line 76 and see if the DAO variable can get overwritten (another thread?)

Comment: I just used another user besides root user for MySQL and it no longer throws the exception.